# zsh: exec format error in Ventura when running a bin file

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, apple-silicon, intel

I still use Snapz Pro as my main screen capture app. I recently upgraded both my M1 Mac Studio and my Intel iMac to Ventura. Because Ambrosia SW is no longer in business and has no website, the only way to enter my license code is to run (i.e., double-click) a bin file named Snapz Pro X License that runs a terminal command. I successfully installed the license this way on the Mac Studio by setting the Terminal app to open in Rosetta. Of course, on the Intel iMac, Rosetta is not needed, but double-clicking the bin file results in the output `zsh: exec format error`. That is the same error I encountered on the Mac Studio before I changed Terminal to Rosetta. Does anyone have a suggestion how to get this command to work on my iMac?

I was mistaken about `bash` helping. Whether I run either `zsh` or `bash`, I get the same problem, that the license file is not a directory. Finder says it is a Unix executable file. Here is the Terminal result for running `cd`. I didn't think it made sense to execute the remaining commands suggested by nohillside because of this error.

[image]

Entering file {license file} results in

[image]

The file I double click is Snapz Pro X License. (Earlier, I had mistakingly shown an image double-clicking the actual app. I deleted that image. Sorry.) GetInfo says the license file is a Unix Executable File. The default for opening it is Terminal. Double-clicking on my M1 Mac activated the Snapz Pro X license with Terminal set to Rosetta. But, double-clicking on the Intel iMac results in an exec format error. It does not activate SnapzPro X. Both computers are running Ventura. Prior to Ventura, I had successfully activated the license file on the Intel iMac by double clicking it. Also, on the Intel Mac, typing "file Snapz Pro License" results in a zlib compressed data message.

Comment: In terminal can you run `file <binary>` to see what type of binary it is

Comment: If by "run file <binary>" you mean to double-click the file, here is the Terminal result. Does this tell us what type of binary it is? Does this help?  Last login: Fri Feb 17 18:38:49 on ttys000
/Users/bud/Library/Preferences/Snapz\ Pro\ X\ License ; exit;
vilmaBuds-iMac-2017 ~ % /Users/bud/Library/Preferences/Snapz\ Pro\ X\ License ; exit;
zsh: exec format error: /Users/bud/Library/Preferences/Snapz Pro X License

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: `file <binary>` assumed some experience with Terminal, but we can take this step by step. Can you select the Snapz Pro X License app in Finder, press Cmd-I and add a screenshot of the "General" section to the question?

Comment: Then, open Terminal, type `cd` followed by a space, drag&drop the License app into the Terminal window (should expand to the path of the application) and press Enter. Type `cd Contents/MacOS`, press Enter, type `file *`, press Enter, and then copy/paste everything from the first `cd` down to the output you got *into* the question (formatted as code, but that we can fix in case you don't know how to format it).

Comment: I am not a programmer, but I am familiar with Terminal basics: cd, pwd, ls, etc. Your steps didn't work because the license file is not an actual app, but, according to GetInfo, a Unix executable .bin file. (I tried to drag & drop the screenshot, but only got its text name).  Here is the Terminal Session.  Last login: Tue Feb 14 23:58:02 on console
bud@Bud-Mac-Studio ~ % cd /Users/bud/Library/Preferences/Snapz\ Pro\ X\ License 
cd: not a directory: /Users/bud/Library/Preferences/Snapz Pro X License
bud@Bud-Mac-Studio ~ % cd Contents/MacOS
cd: no such file or directory: Contents/MacOS

Comment: Please **edit** the question directly, there is a link at the bottom of it for this.

Comment: If the license file is a Unix binary, jus type `file ` followed by a space, drag&drip the binary, and press Enter.

Comment: I‘m a bit confused. Which file do you double-click? On the Mac where double-clicking works, can you do Cmd-I on that file and check which Application is used to open it?

Comment: Please show text as text not images so we can read it

Comment: So, there are two potential sorts of "Binary" file here, especially given Ambrosia is a really old Mac company. Old-school Mac "bin files" were MacBinary - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBinary, an old format for sending over Mac-specific files. On all other OS's a binary is a compiled executable. All help so far here, and your question implies that you're trying to run an an exe. Note, no platform has a .bin that's an executable format. Linux/unix doesn't care about extensions and it's .exe on Windows.

Comment: Continuing from the above, I wonder if we need to decompress your file first. gunzip might do it.